# Are there doclets available for embedding Graphviz DOT code in Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc, graphviz, doclet

After some searching, I have found a lot of doclets, Maven plugins, etc. which automatically generate UML class diagrams using Graphviz.

However, I am looking for a doclet which I can use to embed my own DOT code in my Javadoc, primarily for including sequence diagrams and things like that.

Does such a tool exist?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
/**
* Some sort of graphviz tag or macro, like below:
* <graphviz>
*   digraph graphname {
*     a -> b -> c;
*     b -> d;
*   }
* </graphviz>
*/
```

I am aware that I can embed Graphviz images directly, but I would prefer to have the DOT code version-controlled alongside the Java code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this an interesting idea, so I created a module for https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java that can do this.
https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java#javadoc